# Statistical test - pre and post teaching session

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I am collecting data on people's knowledge of radiation dosages before and after a teaching session. The data is NOT normally distributed. Therefore I will be comparing the MEDIAN of each set of data.

For the pre-teaching data set I have 17 responses. There are 2-3 significant outliers in the data
I am anticipating 10-15 responses for the post-teaching data set.

Would the Mood's median test be appropriate?
Is there any free software that would run this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you show a bit of what the data look like? You mentioned it's measuring knowledge and it's not normal -- but that could still lead to a few different options.

One idea, is perhaps something like inter-rater agreements could be useful if you're looking at seeing if people's knowledge remain the same pre/post by measuring their "knowledge rank". Inter-rater agreements are used to compare whether people in one group rate/compare an object similar to another group (see here [inter-rater agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability)). In this case,

- group A = students pre lesson
- group B = students post lesson

The test-statistic of interest would be [Cohen's Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa).

You could do this for free in R following the tutorial below and the *irr* R package:

- https://www.r-bloggers.com/k-is-for-cohens-kappa/

Comment: An example of the pre-intervention data collection: is radiation dose for scan X in units, U where 1 U = 0.02: 2
4
1
40
1
4
2
2
20
3
2
2
5
2
4
4
15
I would hope post the intervention the numbers tend around 65

Comment: Also, I thought Cohen's Kappa doesn't have a significance value. I would ideally like a test with a significance value

Comment: I'll answer both of your comments in separate posts.

1.) Cohen's Kappa does have a significance value. You calculate an effect size and a subsequent p-value --> see the section on hypothesis testing here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa.

Comment: 2.) So in this case, you want to measure an increase in knowledge? The data tend to be hovering around 0-10 (with a few outliers), and you want the average/median as a whole to increase towards 65. 

The mood's median test assumes the two samples come from an identical population. In this case, on one hand this is true, because it is the same people. On the other, one  group has seen the course and the other hasn't. So justifying the assumptions is tricky.

Comment: Thanks. Given the data example I have given, does Cohen's Kappa still work best then? Thanks

Comment: 2.) cont'd.

On the other hand, mann-whittney test measures whether a distribution is stochastically larger than another, which assumes the two samples come from different "populations".  Again, the assumption issues here are similar to the above. 

The kruskal-wallis seems like a possibility as well. 

Perhaps, try out all three tests and see if the signal is apparent across all three.

Comment: I'd say somewhere between Mood's, Mann-Whitney and Kruskal-wallis, the true assumptions lie. 

I originally thought about Cohen's kappa, but once you showed me the data, I think it's not as useful. Cohen's Kappa measures the agreement of the "order" of the observations, whereas you want to see an increase from one group to the other.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you